# load jsp to div in app engine

Tags: javascript, jsp, google-app-engine

I have an app engine web application, and try to load jsp file to div in JavaScript such as

```
$("#resultList").load("resources/jsp/result.jsp")
```

When I run as web application, it works in local server. However, when I deploy to app engine, it seems that the application cannot find the jsp file. Why it works in local appen engine, but not in remote?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your jsp file is unavailable due to some configuration or file misplacement. To fix that you can try to create a servlet mapping in your web.xml like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>my-jsp-file</servlet-name>
    <!-- jsp files should be placed somewhere under WEB-INF -->
    <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/path/to/jsp.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>my-jsp-file</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/jsp/result.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use relative path to path of the file where you call load ()

Comment: This was flagged as a low quality post, but I'm voting to leave it in place - there isn't enough information in the OP to suggest that this _isn't_ the exact cause of the problem.